# Laravel Queues and changes to job classes

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a project which uses redis and Laravel (5.1) queues.

In our case, after a deployment a specific job started failing, causing a backlog of tens of thousands of jobs in redis. After finding a logic issue in my code within the specific job class, a fix was deployed which also removed a class-scoped variable.

However, as the class is serialised and stored in redis, when the queued jobs retried the queued job then failed as the Laravel worker tried to access a now non-existing class-scope variable. I fixed this issue by issuing a further deployment with the variable back in place.

How can this be avoided in the future? Is there a way to refresh the serialised job code, or a better way to catch this kind of error? The serialised object method used by Laravel in Redis creates a dependency between the queued item and the Laravel code I'd rather just avoid.

Comment: I am interested in an answer to this question also

Comment: @lufc it turns out this has been a badly undocumented Laravel issue. Only about 2 weeks ago the latest documentation was updated to include this which may help you:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#ignoring-missing-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a largely undocumented issue. A recent addition to the documentation states the following which can help resolve the issue through the thrown exception and model class boolean:

*When injecting an Eloquent model into a job, it is automatically serialized before being placed on the queue and restored when the job is processed. However, if the model has been deleted while the job was waiting to be processed by a worker, your job may fail with a  ModelNotFoundException.*

*For convenience, you may choose to automatically delete jobs with missing models by setting your job's deleteWhenMissingModels property to true:*

```php
/**
 * Delete the job if its models no longer exist.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $deleteWhenMissingModels = true;
```

Read about it in context here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#ignoring-missing-models